# Missing partitions MacBook (2006)

Tags: partitioning, macbook

My friend came over recently, with a corrupted MacBook (2006). He doesn't have the Snow Leopard DVD. I used the live cd and booted into Ubuntu 8.04  (no newer version would work) and seems to be working OK. But there are no partitions to install onto. I think this is because Macs use HFS+ and Ubuntu cannot detect it (?)

So, I would need to know how to (Mount?) this hard drive correctly from within Ubuntu. I have no access to OSX, only the "? Folder of death" Can anyone help with this?

[EDIT] I also have a Windows 7 install disk, but that has the same problem of not being able to install, due to the lack of any form of partitioning.

Comment: What do you mean that it has "no partitions?" Was this in the installer, in GParted, or elsewhere? A screen shot might be helpful if you don't know how to explain this. Alternatively, post the output of `sudo gparted /dev/sda print` typed in a Terminal window.

Comment: I probably should have just said that "No devices were found" Both within installer and Gparted

Comment: A device is a physical piece of hardware, like a hard disk. If that can't be found, then chances are it's dead and needs physical replacement. As I said, though, more precision in reporting may be helpful. If necessary, take a digital photo of the screen that shows the problem and post it.